# Open file with unicode filename using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, unicode

I would like to open a file with Unicode characters in the pathname by using Boost. I am currently using "**file_source**" class. [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file.html) is the synopsis of the structure I am using:

```
namespace boost { namespace iostreams {

template<typename Ch>
class basic_file_source {
public:
   typedef Ch                      char_type;
   typedef implementation-defined  category;
   basic_file_source( const std::string& path,
                   std::ios_base::openmode mode =
                       std::ios_base::in );
   bool is_open() const;
   ...
};

typedef basic_file_source<char>     file_source;
typedef basic_file_source<wchar_t>  wfile_source;

} } // End namespace boost::iostreams
```

As you can see constructors of both "**file_source**" and "**wfile_source**" take path as "**std::string**". But I can represent my file path with UTF-16. How can I pass this path argument to these constructors so that I can open the necessary file ?

Or is there any other way to properly open file with Unicode path-names using Boost ?

Comment: On many systems the proper way to use a Unicode filename in C++ is to have it stored as a `std::string` containing UTF-8. Have you tried that? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/default_encoding_under_windows.html

Comment: I know you said boost but.. Use WINAPI for Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames What do you think Boost uses on windows?

Comment: @sehe I cannot tell if you are being sarcastic or not.. Seeing as you have 100k+ rep and OP posted a link to the boost documentation and the source-code as well, you can clearly tell it uses streams and not WINAPI.. Which takes an "std::string".. It says: "it is a wrapper for std::basic_filebuf".

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Oops. I scanned it a bit too quickly. I /assumed/ it /of course/ used Boost Filesystem, which very much know how to do the right thing on Windows. And, yes, whether or not iostreams are used is hardly relevant for the filenaming part, unless you doubt whether e.g. MSVC is able to ship a standard library that works on their own OS. I agree, it doesn't look like this is what the OP is using :(

Comment: Don't worry, I'd probably have assumed that too if it wasn't for my urge to click all links in posts and forums.. lol bad habits.